# index out of bounds error why?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

The line `x.set(7,y)` in the code below is throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, and I can't figure out why. Can you help?

```
LinkedList<myClass> x = new LinkedList<myClass>();
x = MyArrayList.get(7);
Iterator<myClass> itr = x.iterator();
myClass y = new myClass();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    y = itr.next();
    if (z.methodCallToGetStr().equals(y.methodCallToGetStr()))//z is a myClass object
    {
        y.incCount();
        x.set(7, y);
        break;
```

Comment: It seems `x = MyArrayList.get(7)` doesn't have at least 8 elements as you are trying to set on index 7

Comment: What makes you confident that you *shouldn't* get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?  Nothing in what you presented tells me anything about how many elements `x` has.

Comment: Please use names starting with a capital for classes, and not for fields/variables, so MyClass and myArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MyArrayList.get(7) creates 7 elements, these elements are numbered from 0 to 6. The 7th one is just off the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

x could be initialized at null, same can be applied to y, this helps you to use less memory.
Anyway with x=MyArrayList.get(7) you are changing its reference from the new list to the list with index 7 in MyArrayList (I presume this is an ArrayList>) so with x.set(7, y) you are setting the element with index 7 in the list with index 7 in the array list to y.
But I don't think you can assume that x is long enough so it's better to change the condition of the if to

```
 if (z.methodCallToGetStr().equals(y.methodCallToGetStr()) && x.size() > 7)
```

I think you wanted to move the element equal to z to MyArrayList[7][7], but if the arraylist and the sub linked list are not long enough you should fill them to made them long enough.